# Creating Containers in OpenVZ

Tags: ubuntu, openvz

After using the instructions I found on http://www.unixmen.com/install-and-configure-openvz-in-ubuntu/ I installed OpenVZ on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, which is running in WMware Workstation 10.0.3. Then I moved to http://www.unixmen.com/how-to-create-openvz-container-in-openvz/.

In the tutorial, they download CentOS 7, but because I can't use 64-bit versions under my VMware Workstation (due to an option unavailable in my BIOS), I chose to download an older, 32-bit version of CentOS. I unpacked the .tar file after download.

When I entered the command

```
 root@box1:/etc/vz/template/cache# vzctl create 101 --ostemplate centos-6-x86
```

to create the first virtual machine I get these:

```
Warning: CT config file already exists, not applying a default config sample.
It might lead to incomplete CT configuration, you can use --applyconfig to fix.
Error: diskspace not set (required for ploop)
Creation of container private area failed
```

Why do I get that error? Is there something to be done about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have somehow made an incomplete config file for CT 101, namely `/etc/vz/conf/101.conf`.  If you're confident you have nothing important in CT 101, you can just destroy it (or manually remove `/etc/vz/conf/101.conf`) then try again creating CT 101.

```
vzctl destroy 101
vzctl create 101 --ostemplate centos-6-x86
```

And I must correct several misunderstandings in the site you cite.

- You don't have to download template files by yourself.  Recent `vzctl create` will automatically download it on behalf of you.  You can specify [your nearest mirror site](https://openvz.org/Download_mirrors) in `/etc/vz/download.conf`.  See `vztmpl-dl` manpage for details.
- You don't have to unpack tar+gz template files.  Just put as it is in `/srv/vz/template/cache/` when you've bothered to download one.
- You should always use `vzctl set CTID --save` to configure CT rather than directly edit its config file:

  ```
  vzctl set 101 --save --ram 256M --swap 512M --diskspace 2G:2.2G
  ```

  Especially regarding `diskspace`, any changes in a config file won't be reflected in the ploop layout.